# Catch exception thrown by another class?

Tags: c#, exception

I thought I could catch an exception thrown by another class in my project, but I must be doing it wrong.  In the first class, I'm surrounding my call to the other class with a try/catch block:

```
try
{    
    ImportPowerPoint.CreateTitle(textBoxPpt.Text, textBoxPkg.Text);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

In the second class, this is where I'm throwing the exception:

```
if (!_layoutMap[(int)Layouts.A].ContainsValue(Fields.Title))
    throw new FormatException("Standard (A) Layout does not contain a title.");

if (!_layoutMap[(int)Layouts.A].ContainsValue(Fields.Txt1))
    throw new FormatException("Standard (A) Layout does not contain a txt1.");

if (!_layoutMap[(int)Layouts.A].ContainsValue(Fields.Prompt))
  throw new FormatException("Standard (A) Layout does not contain a prompt.");
```

When I run the program, it breaks immediately where the exception is thrown, instead of displaying the error window that I defined in the try/catch block.  Am I not handling this try/catch correctly?

For clarification, I'm forcing the exception to occur by removing certain pieces from the PowerPoint that I'm parsing.  When the program fails, for instance, because I removed the `Title` Field, the exception thrown is of type FormatException.  Shouldn't my `catch` in the calling class handle this?

EDIT: I think I may have found out something that is causing this to happen.  The exception being thrown is in another thread.  So, since it's in another thread, could this mean that this is why my try/catch isn't catching the exception?

Comment: Just to clarify are you saying that the `ImportPowerPoint.CreateTitle` method is throwing the exception that isn't being caught? Because that looks like it should catch all `FormatException`s and show your message box.

Comment: Actually, and this may be important, the actual exception is being thrown in another class that is called from the `ImportPowerPoint.CreateTitle`.  I was thinking the exception would be  caught by the calling class no matter where the exception occurred, whether in the immediately called class, or a class called from that class, if that makes sense.

Comment: If that method calls things on other classes then the catch should still catch. The fact that the code is in other classes is not a problem (and indeed is usually expected since often you are catching exceptions in framework classes and not your own code). Are you definitely in this piece of code (and its not throwing the exception from somewhere else in your code)?

Comment: You may want to check the InnerException property on the exception you are catching in the outer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here appears to be because this is a multithreaded program.  I'm looking at using the [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to handle my exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It is breaking in the IDE to notify that the exception is thrown. If you press F5 again to continue running, your `catch` handler should be hit.

Comment: This is true, Theres a break window in most IDEs that can give you detail when your program breaks

Comment: Unfortunately, what's happening in my case is that after I hit the F5 key to continue, it just pops the message back up again.  I hit F5 over and over and the program just breaks and the message pops up saying 'FormatException was unhandled'.

Comment: What does the call stack look like when this happens? - is the throw location being called via your trap?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing class-related about exceptions. Your calling code (`ImportPowerPoint.CreateTitle(...);`) should be able to catch exceptions thrown by `CreateTitle()`.

See if your Visual Studio is configured to catch all exceptions (opposed to catching only unhandled ones):

1. Go to the 'Debug' menu
2. Select 'Exceptions...'
3. Uncheck check boxes under the 'Thrown' column

You would typically want the IDE to catch unhandled exceptions, so I would keep the other column checked.